# how do i calculate the heat recovery and outlet temperatures of a heat exchanger only knowing exchanger size and inlet fluid conditions?

Tags: heat-transfer

all of the heat exchanger calculations i can find assume you are trying to design a heat exchanger to get your required temperature at the outlet or a specific Btu recovery. my issue is that i have a heat exchanger that is predefined and i want to know what the outlet temperatures and of both sides will end up being and how many btu/hr it will exchange. in this example lets say it is a counter flow tube in tube 10" inner pipe and 12" outer pipe with .06" thick stainless walls and 50' long. the only things that are known are the inlet temperatures and flow rates. i want outlet temps and btu recovery.

Comment: what about efficiency?

Comment: you would need the heat transfer coefficient for the existing heat exchanger.  Theoretically you could calculate the heat flux through the materials according to flow, but much better is just measuring it.